# Marker Clusterer, cluster at 1 marker also

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I am using marker clusterer with google maps. All is working very well but I would like to know how to cluster a marker even if there is only 1 marker with that grid. At the moment on page load you will see the odd marker darted around and others are within a clustered icon. I would like all even the single markers to display a cluster icon also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the option `minimumClusterSize` to 1 (default is 2)

```
new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{minimumClusterSize:1});
```